# let npapi windowed plugin droppable

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, npapi, chromium-embedded

I create a windowed npapi plugin on windows, and expect when dragging a file over the plugin, the cursor shows the 
**accepting drop** effect.

For the aim, I tried the following two methods, which both work well in native window app.

1. call **DragAcceptFiles(hwn, TRUE)** for the npapi plugin's native window handler
2. create a **[IDropTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679679(v=vs.85).aspx)** class for the handler

But both show **forbidden drop** cursor. Any idea?

A plus, the program's architecture is Qt embedding **CEF**.

Comment: it will depend on the platform and browser; drag/drop is not supported consistently across different browsers, and FireBreath doesn't have an abstraction for this (yet; you could write one if you want), so you'll have to get into the internals and figure it out yourself.

Comment: Today I tried to inject dragover/dragmove event listener, still failed. I will read FireBreath's code to take my chance. Hope could find some workaround. Thanks.

Comment: Note that this might behave different between browsers. Did you subclass the window? Did you try adding your own child window and enabling dnd on that?

Comment: The NPAPI plugin is loadded by chromium-embeded-framework (cef). I use spy++, and confirmed there is no child window anymore. I searched FireBreath source code and examples, found nothing useful for this problem.

Comment: It seems very strange, other cef windows would receive HITTEST window message, but the NPAPI window receives nothing when dragging over.

Comment: You'll need to be using a windowed plugin, and Georg's suggestion is a good one; create your own child window and do dnd on that

Answer (score 0):

@Georg Fritzsche and @taxilian give the answer, add a child window to the windowed npapi plugin.

And do drag and drop in the child window.

In my project, I use another solution, described below.

Provide a drag move api in windowed npapi plugin.

This native api handles mouse over test, cursor set, fire custom event so etc.

When drag and drop started, trigger a timer in javascript end to call the api.